# Mysql allows access for root user, but acces is denied for user with all privileges as root user

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have PHPMyAdmin and MySQL installed on WAMP, and running.

The user `root` is created by default in PHPmyAdmin, and is not using a password.

I use a interface to log in to the MySQL. Ok, when I pass the login details:

```
Datasource : dbi:mysql:foobar:localhost:3306 
 User Name : root
     Auth  :
```

Dbi stands for database engine, `foobar` is the table, localhost = address, and port. 
I get access to the database, everything works fine.

Okay, then I create a new user in PHPMyAdmin.

The new user is `johnsmith` with the password `foobar`. He get all privilges, same as the root

It looks like this:

[image]

So in the same interface, I fill the following:

```
 Datasource : dbi:mysql:foobar:localhost:3306 
 User Name  : johnsmith
 Auth       : foobar
```

But for this user I got an error from mysql:

```
 Access denied for user 'johnsmith'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Tested it again with `root`-user, it gets access, but the user `johnsmith` don't get access, even when he have all privileges and admin rights. So I suspect I'm missing a feature in PHPAdmin..

Could anyone point out where I went wrong? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add localhost to johnsmith with the same pattern like root.

Comment: Tested it, it didn't help. What does the `%` means then? It was filled by PHPmyadmin by default.

Comment: Take a look here for the explanation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html and flush your privileges.

Comment: i would delete and add again, it works quite oftern

Comment: @Dagon that's not a logical thing. And yes, I tried that earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this:

```
CREATE USER 'johnsmith'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'foobar';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'johnsmith'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'johnsmith'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'foobar';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'johnsmith'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'johnsmith'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'foobar';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'johnsmith'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

For whatever reason `localhost` is treated differently than others, and the `%` wildcard doesn't seem to apply to it.  Then you have to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` for it to take effect.

Comment: It worked, thank you for that. But I have another problem by now. The database is moderated by some other. My account currently have % as host account, and I can't change it. Another suggestion, perhaps?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: For example, I'm John Smith in this case, but with `%` as host instead `localhost`. I have access to PHPMyAdmin. I have all rights, but not admin rights. I guess I cannot change the host then for my account.

Comment: Do you have access to the root account?  If you need to grant admin privileges you just add `WITH GRANT OPTION` when you run the `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` line.  But you need the grant option already to be able to do that

Comment: localhost is different because it uses sockets instead of going over TCP/IP

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' after you created the user?
MySQL needs te re-read the privileges table in order to see the new changes.

Comment: I did, without any result unfortunately. However, I notice this is your first answer after 3.5 years!! (Gefeliciteerd, het moet eens van komen!). For that, I upvoted your post even I didn't helped in my case. :-)

Comment: Bedankt! :p
Haven't been here for a while - so it's good to be back.